# How to Use Like in Linq Dynamics?

Tags: linq-to-sql, microsoft-dynamics

I want to achieve something like this :-

var DB = new DALDataContext();
DB.Domains.Where("Name Like @p0",new [] {"field"});

Answer (score 0):

use `String.Contains()` property for this condition.
something like this `source.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("someName"));`

Also you can use `SqlMethods.Like()` from System.Data.Linq.SqlClient namespace

example:

```
       `var query = from s in Source 
        where SqlMethods.Like(s.Name, "%someName%")
        select s;`
```

Comment: this is not valid in Linq Dynamics (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Comment: what is mean "is not valid"? is it compile?

Comment: try to use Contains() http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/11/23/LINQToSQLLIKEOperatorGeneratingLIKESQLServer.aspx